# How to make Scrapy save images to a remote server?

Tags: python, image, scrapy, remote-server

Currently the downloaded images are all saved to the local machine, but what I want is save the images directly to a remote server (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), is that anyway to do this within Scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Scrapy supports storing files in Amazon S3.

To set up image storage to one of the backend use appropriate backend scheme and path:

```
IMAGES_STORE = 's3://bucket/images'
```

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=image%20pipelines#supported-storage

However you can create custom `FileStore` class for example inheriting from Scrapy's `FSFileStore` https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L42
and then create custom `ImagePipeline` setting scheme you'd like to use, for ex.:

```
class CustomFtpImagePipeline(ImagePipeline):
    STORE_SCHEMES = {
        'ftp': MyFTPFilesStore,
    }
```

then just use `IMAGES_STORE` setting with appropriate scheme:

```
IMAGES_STORE = 'ftp://path_to_dir/on_ftp_server
```

Comment: I know about that, but what I need is to save the images to another server that I'm using, not to Amazon S3.

Comment: Still couldn't get to work. Where do I have to write the code that is responsible of directing scrapy to use ftp to save files to the remote server? Which methods to override? Sorry, but I'm totally new to python, if you could provide me some working code to start with I'll be grateful.